# Spring "Redis String Template" Appends Values instead of Replacing

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I'm new to Redis+Spring. What's the difference between

```java
stringRedisTemplate.boundValueOps(key).setIfAbsent("STARTED", timeout)
stringRedisTemplate.boundValueOps(key).set("STOPPED", timeout);
```

and

```java
stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().setIfAbsent(key, "STARTED", timeout)
stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, "STOPPED", timeout);
```

My problem is the former **appends** the new value while the latter **replaces** it. What am I missing here?
What is the correct way to create (atomically) a simple string value and keep updating it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference between `BoundValueOperations` and `ValueOperations` other than `BoundValueOperations` does not require the *key* for each and every operation as it keeps the *key* internally and delegates to `ValueOperations` applying the very value.

```java
BoundValueOperations<String, String> keyBoundOps = stringRedisTemplate.boundValueOps(key);
keyBoundOps.setIfAbsent("STARTED", timeout);
keyBoundOps.set("STOPPED", timeout);
```

When it comes to the specific commands please have a look at the Redis documentation for [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set) with different *Options* like `NX` (Only set the key if it does not already exist) and [SETEX](https://redis.io/commands/setex).

`setIfAbsent("STARTED", timeout)` -> `SET key STARTED EX timeout NX`.
`set("STOPPED", timeout)` -> `SETEX key timeout STOPPED`.

You can see all commands arriving at the server using [MONITOR](https://redis.io/commands/monitor).

If there's an issue with one of the operations sending the wrong command, please file a ticket in the bug [tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS).

Comment: "My problem is the former appends the new value while the latter replaces it. What am I missing here?"
So is it a bug?

Comment: None of the methods should ever send `APPEND`. Do you have a snippet to run that shows what's going on?

Comment: Not anymore, this is weird. I'm 100% positive it was failing (while converting the string value to an enum, I saw the error message with the appended value). Now my tests are passing. :facepalm: